# pip install causes error: bash: /usr/bin/vendor_perl/pip: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, pacman, pip

I have installed the `python-pip` package with the pacman package manager as I am using Manjaro Linux.  I have cloned [this](https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django_19) repository where there is a `requirements.txt` in the folder `tango_with_django_19/code/`.

However, when I run the following command, I get an error:

```
$ pip install requirements.txt 
bash: /usr/bin/vendor_perl/pip: No such file or directory
```

What might be causing this and how can I overcome this error to install the requirements for the django web app?

**EDIT:**

My output of `yaourt -Ss pip`is the following, which suggests that I have not installed the [perl pip](https://metacpan.org/pod/pip) package from the AUR:

```
$ yaourt -Ss pip
.
.
.
aur/pip 1.2-1 (37) (1.25)
    Wraps programs to use them as filters.
.
.
.
```

Should I simply remove the perl pip from /usr/bin/vendor_perl or is there a way to specifically run python-pip?

Comment: For some reasons you installed both Python's `pip`, and a [Perl `pip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pip).

Comment: @SatoKatsura Do you know how I can specifically run Python's pip?

Comment: Remove the Perl `pip`, and complain to the maintainer.  You might also need to reinstall Python `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [perl pip](https://metacpan.org/pod/pip) package is installed due to the `/usr/bin/vendor_perl/pip` in the error, I needed to specifically run the python-pip program.  To do this, I ran the following line:

```
$ /usr/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which specifically ran the python pip package, avoiding the error.  In my case, I needed to run it with `sudo`.